# How do I change a zero price to TBC on the category view

Tags: price

I have a number of products in a category but 2 of them have a 0.00 price which I need hiding (just the price not the product) in the category view. How do I do this?

Comment: You want to hide the price for 2 products? Or all products that are 0$ ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  You should post your attempts so we can help you more effectively.

Comment: @JamesCowie you should write this as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to hide the price for all 0.00 priced products.

I would open up price.phtml that is applicable to your theme and add a new conditional check for 0.00 pricing and replace with your label. If there is no price.phtml in your theme package use best practice and copy from base/default into your themes namespace and make customisations there.

There are many checks in this template for different product types so you will need to be more specific with your stores configuration if you require more help